# Need to apply border for array Elements based on the open and closed Brackets

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an array

```
Attributedata = ['(', 'Keyword Atribute', 'OR, 'AND', 'Call Atribute', 'Sentiment Atribute', ')'];
```

i will selecting and displaying in UI.
but once the ( and ) are selected need to hide it and apply border for content.

Demo
selecting UI like ( Keyword Atribute OR Call Atribute ) AND Sentiment.
Once the Bracket closed it should be like below output

output

---

### |Keyword Atribute OR Call Atribute|  AND Sentiment

How to achieve the above.

Comment: Please show us something that you've tried.

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uczc63?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
var newLine = null;
this.Attributedata.forEach(item => {
  if (item == "(") {
    newLine = "|";
  } else if (item == "AND") {
     newLine += `|`;
  } else if (item == ")") {
    this.outputs.push(newLine)
    newLine = null;
  } else {
    newLine += ` ${item}`;
  }
});
```

Note: Your question is not very clear. I hope this will help you, you can make little modifications as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want vertical border for `"("` and `")"` then you can use pipe symbol `"|"` and you can replace those with `"|"` like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let a of Attributedata">{{a == "(" || a == ")" ? "|" : a }}</span>
```